# CATransform3D breaks UIView into two parts before animation

Tags: uiview, transform, axis, layer, catransform3d

I have a problem with CATransform3D. 
When I try to do a Y axis rotation, the UIView breaks into two parts before animation starts.

An image is worth a thousand words...

[image]

Here's the code:

```
CATransform3D _3Dt = CATransform3DMakeRotation(2.0 * M_PI, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                 animations:^{
                     view.layer.transform = _3Dt;
                 }];
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

The problem was the `layer.zPosition`

Here's is the final code:

```
view.layer.zPosition = CGRectGetWidth(view.bounds);
CATransform3D _3Dt = CATransform3DMakeRotation(2.0 * M_PI, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                 animations:^{
                     view.layer.transform = _3Dt;
                 }];
```

Thanks!